# How to use image-slice in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, slice, cairo, node-canvas

I tried using `image-slice` to slice into multiple part using node js.

I tried installing `npm i image-to-slices`, `sudo port install cairo`, `npm i canvas` and `brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib` but still show error `require node-canvas` on the server side node.js

Here  is the i have tried to slice image:

```
 var imageToSlices = require('image-to-slices');

 exports.sliceImage=(request, response)=>{


var lineXArray = [100, 200];
var lineYArray = [100, 200];
var source = './public/images/Bitmap001.png'; // width: 300, height: 300

 imageToSlices(source, lineXArray, lineYArray, {
 saveToDir: './public/images/bit001.png'
 }, function() {
 console.log('the source image has been sliced into 9 sections!');
  });


  }//sliceImage
```

Console output error:

```
 Error: Require node-canvas on the server-side Node.js
at ImageClipper.__createImage (/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/image-clipper/lib/clipper.js:456:13)
at ImageClipper.loadImageFromUrl (/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/image-clipper/lib/clipper.js:83:20)
at ImageClipper.image (/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/image-clipper/lib/clipper.js:120:10)
at imageClipper (/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/image-clipper/lib/index.js:36:15)
at ImageToSlices.slice (/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/image-to-slices/lib/image-to-slices.js:212:3)
at ImageToSlicesFactory (/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/image-to-slices/lib/index.js:22:17)
at exports.sliceImage (/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/app/controllers/ApiController.js:843:1)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
```

Comment: Try explaining what you want to achieve also. That helps a lot to give a valuable answer.

Comment: @maxpaj just added code to slice image to multiple image while running node js file it shows error..

Comment: Can you see `node-canvas` or `canvas` package in your `node-modules` folder? The error indicates indeed that node-canvas is not available.

Comment: canvas module is there but not node-canvas was not there @maxpaj

Comment: @maxpaj https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-to-slices image to slice npm

Comment: If `canvas` is installed correctly, you should be able to do `const canvas = require("canvas"); if (canvas && canvas.Image) { console.log("Canvas is installed!"); } else { console.log("Canvas is not installed yet."); }`

Comment: @maxpaj it shows Canvas is installed!

Comment: @maxpaj any updates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Digging around in the code I found that you can specify which `canvas` you want to use, through the use of `clipperOptions` in the configuration.

Try this:

```
var imageToSlices = require('image-to-slices');
var lineXArray = [100, 200];
var lineYArray = [100, 200];
var source = './public/images/Bitmap001.png'; // width: 300, height: 300

imageToSlices(source, lineXArray, lineYArray, {
    saveToDir: '.',
    clipperOptions: {
        canvas: require('canvas')
    }    
}, function() {
    console.log('the source image has been sliced into 9 sections!');
});
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this.
How can we break an image into six pieces of equal size?

Comment: @IbadShaikh I don't know, but you could write a new question about it!

Comment: I did it using : 
var lineXArray = [350, 650]
var lineYArray = [375]

Comment: Hi @maxpaj. Is there any way to require *canvas* using import syntax because in my project I'm using "type": "module" es6 import syntax.

Comment: I don't know, it should be doable. Did you try `import * as canvas from "canvas"`?